# LDAP query for group in group

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Is there a good way to write an LDAP query that checks group memberships recursively? I have a custom attribute on a group that contains a list of objects (users and groups). My query works fine for users.

Existing stripped down query

```
(&(myList=cn=usr23453))
```

where myList is a multi-value DN.

I apologize for use of incorrect terms and so on. AD and LDAP programming is kinda new to me.

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe the filter syntax is powerful enough for this, unlike say SQL. You have to write some code.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right. I was hoping not to have to do multiple roundtrips to the AD.

Comment: My proposed solution to this is to simply get all the groups the user belongs to and add them to the main query. That way I can get away with only to LDAP-queries no matter the workload.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are tying to do, but, To Resolve nested security groups:

```
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=user,CN=Users,DC=DOM,DC=NT)
```

Where CN=user,CN=Users,DC=DOM,DC=NT is the Fully Distinguished name of a user entry.

-jim

Comment: This is an extensible matching search filter Microsoft calls "LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN"We explain a lot about this on this page and related pages:http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941

Comment: So it searches the parent chain until it finds a match on DN. How exactly does that address nested groups?